# Suzuki GSX 150 fuel knob position

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, suzuki, gsx

How do I identify the GSXR 150 fuel knob location?

- ON POSITION.
- RESERVE POSITION
- OFF POSITION.

Can someone give me an idea of the various positions based upon a clock face?

Thank you.

Comment: The OP is just asking which position the fuel valve has to be in for each: On; Reserve; Off. This isn't a hard question, if you are familiar with the bike. Absolutely a valid question and deserves to stay open. Assuming the OP's first language is not English.

Comment: What year and full model number is the bike.  Is it a GSX or a GSXR?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Isn't there actually a "Gixxer" model? I realize the GSXR comes out as being that (if spoken) ... but looking on the Interwebz it appeared there was actually a model name for the [smaller bikes called a Gixxer](http://www.suzukimotorcycle.co.in/GixxerPrice.aspx).

Comment: Yes, there is an Indian Gixxer model.

Answer (score 1):

"Down" should always be "open", and you can find out where is "close" position. Probably right or left. So "Up" will be "reserve".